# Non-comformable arrays error when using xts series in a logistic regression

Tags: r, xts

I'm using xts time series, originally converted from type ts, in a logstic regression, but I get

```
Error in `*.default`(x[good, , drop = FALSE], w) : non-conformable arrays
```

Example:

```
success <- as.xts(ts(sample(0:10, 100, replace=T), start=1970, fr=12))
failure <- 10-success
x <- as.xts(ts(rnorm(100), start=1970, fr=12))
glm(cbind(success, failure) ~ x, family=binomial)
```

However, if the series are converted to class `ts` or just a vector than there is no error:

```
glm(cbind(as.ts(success), as.ts(failure)) ~ as.ts(x), family=binomial)
glm(cbind(as.vector(success), as.vector(failure)) ~ as.vector(x), family=binomial)
```

Is there a way to avoid the error while working with the original xts series?

Comment: +1 great question. The problem is caused by the default of `drop=FALSE` in `[.xts`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is caused by the default of `drop=FALSE` in `[.xts`.  You can avoid this by specifying the `data` argument, which will be converted to a data.frame.

```
glm(cbind(success, failure) ~ x, data=merge(success,failure,x), family=binomial)
```